# Warning: org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.DummyGraphics2d

Tags: android, proguard

When i try use from proguard these errors and warnings are comming and APK file not builds:

**Warnings:**

> org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.DummyGraphics2d: can't find superclass
>   or interface java.awt.Graphics2D
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.EscherGraphics: can't find superclass or
>   interface java.awt.Graphics
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.EscherGraphics2d: can't find superclass
>   or interface java.awt.Graphics2D
>   org.apache.poi.sl.draw.DrawSimpleShape$1: can't find superclass or
>   interface javax.xml.stream.EventFilter
>   org.apache.poi.sl.draw.Drawable$DrawableHint: can't find superclass or
>   interface java.awt.RenderingHints$Key 
>   org.apache.poi.sl.draw.PathGradientPaint: can't find superclass or
>   interface java.awt.Paint
>   org.apache.poi.sl.draw.PathGradientPaint$PathGradientContext: can't
>   find superclass or interface java.awt.PaintContext
>   org.apache.poi.sl.draw.SLGraphics: can't find superclass or interface
>   java.awt.Graphics2D    org.apache.poi.sl.draw.geom.PresetGeometries$1:
>   can't find superclass or interface javax.xml.stream.EventFilter
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find
>   referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl: can't find
>   referenced class java.beans.Transient 
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl: can't find
>   referenced class java.beans.ConstructorProperties 
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl: can't find
>   referenced class java.beans.Transient 
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl: can't find
>   referenced class java.beans.ConstructorProperties 
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl: can't find
>   referenced class java.beans.Transient 
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl: can't find
>   referenced class java.beans.ConstructorProperties 
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl: can't find
>   referenced class java.beans.Transient 
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl: can't find
>   referenced class java.beans.ConstructorProperties 
>   io.jsonwebtoken.impl.Base64Codec: can't find referenced class
>   javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter
>   io.jsonwebtoken.impl.crypto.EllipticCurveProvider: can't find
>   referenced class org.bouncycastle.jce.ECNamedCurveTable
>   org.apache.poi.ddf.EscherMetafileBlip: can't find referenced class
>   java.awt.Rectangle     org.apache.poi.ddf.EscherMetafileBlip: can't find
>   referenced class java.awt.Dimension
>   org.apache.poi.ddf.EscherMetafileBlip: can't find referenced class
>   java.awt.Rectangle     org.apache.poi.ddf.EscherMetafileBlip: can't find
>   referenced class java.awt.Dimension
>   org.apache.poi.ddf.EscherPictBlip: can't find referenced class
>   java.awt.Rectangle     org.apache.poi.ddf.EscherPictBlip: can't find
>   referenced class java.awt.Dimension

**Errors:**

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Job failed, see logs for details  at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.transform(ProGuardTransform.java:207)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:239)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:235)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.     at
>   proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:485)    at
>   proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:271)   at
>   proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:113)  at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.BaseProguardAction.runProguard(BaseProguardAction.java:64)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.doMinification(ProGuardTransform.java:262)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.access$000(ProGuardTransform.java:65)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform$1.run(ProGuardTransform.java:176)
>     at com.android.builder.tasks.Job.runTask(Job.java:47)   at
>   com.android.build.gradle.tasks.SimpleWorkQueue$EmptyThreadContext.runTask(SimpleWorkQueue.java:41)
>     at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:282)  ... 1
>   more

**proguad-rules.pro file**

```
# apache
-keep public class org.apache.poi.** {*;}
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
-dontwarn org.apache.poi.**
```

This solved the issue for me.